# transforming DF into time series for dynamic lm estimation

Tags: r, time-series, lag, lm

I have imported and stored in a dataframe some variables to perfom basic regressions and statistical analysis. Starting from the time series of these variables I built up my DF and attached to it also a Date variable, to have a clear reference time when plotting. The DF looks broadly like this (I take just a random part):

```
     time        ffr      cpi          gap
266 2013-04-01    0.12   0.75         -4.17
267 2013-07-01    0.09   1.90         -3.85
268 2013-10-01    0.09   1.28         -3.34
269 2014-01-01    0.07   1.32         -3.94
270 2014-04-01    0.09   1.98         -3.24
271 2014-07-01    0.09   1.31         -2.60
272 2014-10-01    0.10  -0.02         -2.47
273 2015-01-01    0.11  -0.06         -2.68
274 2015-04-01    0.12   2.02         -2.10
275 2015-07-01    0.13   1.24         -1.98
276 2015-10-01    0.16   0.78         -2.11
```

Now, when I run a simple regression like

```
reg1<-lm(df, ffr ~ cpi + gap)
```

everything works fine with expected results. But when I try a sligthly more sophisticated model with an autoregressive part, lags and forwards, things gets quite messy, and the solutions I found on the Web do not seem to work in my case. Below are some exemples:

```
reg2<-lm(df, ffr ~ cpi + gap + lag(ffr))
```

this gives a perfect fit, because what actually happens is that ffr is regressed on iteself without lags.
Then I follow what I find elsewhere and turn the dataframe in the time series format, by

```
df<-xts(df, order.by=df$time)
```

and then

```
reg3<-lm(df, ffr ~ cpi + gap + lag(ffr))
```

which actually gives super strange results, since it appears -- in my understanding -- that all the observations of cpi, gap and ffr are used as *variables*.
Here the ouput of the regression

```
Call:
lm(formula = ffr ~ cpi + gap + lag(ffr), data = small2)

Residuals:
ALL 11 residuals are 0: no residual degrees of freedom!

Coefficients: (16 not defined because of singularities)
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)         3         NA      NA       NA
cpi-0.06            1         NA      NA       NA
cpi 0.75            2         NA      NA       NA
cpi 0.78            4         NA      NA       NA
cpi 1.24            3         NA      NA       NA
cpi 1.28           -1         NA      NA       NA
cpi 1.31           -1         NA      NA       NA
cpi 1.32           -2         NA      NA       NA
cpi 1.90           -1         NA      NA       NA
cpi 1.98           -1         NA      NA       NA
cpi 2.02            2         NA      NA       NA
gap-2.10           NA         NA      NA       NA
gap-2.11           NA         NA      NA       NA
gap-2.47           NA         NA      NA       NA
gap-2.60           NA         NA      NA       NA
gap-2.68           NA         NA      NA       NA
gap-3.24           NA         NA      NA       NA
gap-3.34           NA         NA      NA       NA
gap-3.85           NA         NA      NA       NA
gap-3.94           NA         NA      NA       NA
gap-4.17           NA         NA      NA       NA
lag(ffr)0.09       NA         NA      NA       NA
lag(ffr)0.10       NA         NA      NA       NA
lag(ffr)0.11       NA         NA      NA       NA
lag(ffr)0.12       NA         NA      NA       NA
lag(ffr)0.13       NA         NA      NA       NA

lag(ffr)0.16       NA         NA      NA       NA

Residual standard error: NA on 0 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:     NA, Adjusted R-squared:     NA 
F-statistic:    NA on 10 and 0 DF,  p-value: NA
```

and the following warnings

```
Warning messages:
1: In model.response(mf, "numeric") :
  using type = "numeric" with a factor response will be ignored
2: In Ops.factor(y, z$residuals) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors
3: In Ops.factor(r, 2) : ‘^’ not meaningful for factors
```

The same applies when using `zoo` instead of `xts`. Then I try the `dyn` package, with the data being both in the form of a dataframe and a xts/zoo object: nothing works and I get a perfect fit and usual errors, respectively. Using the package `dynlm`, nothing changes. Any hints or ideas about what is goin on?

Ah, after transforming the orginal dataframe in xts, it looks like this

```
           time         ffr    cpi     gap    
2013-04-01 "2013-04-01" "0.12" " 0.75" "-4.17"
2013-07-01 "2013-07-01" "0.09" " 1.90" "-3.85"
2013-10-01 "2013-10-01" "0.09" " 1.28" "-3.34"
2014-01-01 "2014-01-01" "0.07" " 1.32" "-3.94"
2014-04-01 "2014-04-01" "0.09" " 1.98" "-3.24"
2014-07-01 "2014-07-01" "0.09" " 1.31" "-2.60"
2014-10-01 "2014-10-01" "0.10" "-0.02" "-2.47"
2015-01-01 "2015-01-01" "0.11" "-0.06" "-2.68"
2015-04-01 "2015-04-01" "0.12" " 2.02" "-2.10"
2015-07-01 "2015-07-01" "0.13" " 1.24" "-1.98"
2015-10-01 "2015-10-01" "0.16" " 0.78" "-2.11"
```

So I wonder if the whole problem is that the transformation fails to convert the DF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply calculate the lag yourself, using `shift` to add a new column to your dataframe:

```
df$lag1 <- shift(df$ffr)
reg3<-lm(ffr ~ cpi + gap + lag1, df)
```

Result using your 11 rows:

```
> summary(reg3)

Call:
lm(formula = ffr ~ cpi + gap + lag1, data = df)

Residuals:
      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
-0.012355 -0.006234 -0.004345  0.003007  0.019277 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)  0.0983353  0.0362563   2.712   0.0350 *
cpi         -0.0009486  0.0058926  -0.161   0.8774  
gap          0.0215892  0.0066774   3.233   0.0178 *
lag1         0.6821619  0.2476126   2.755   0.0331 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.01254 on 6 degrees of freedom
  (1 observation deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.844, Adjusted R-squared:  0.7659 
F-statistic: 10.82 on 3 and 6 DF,  p-value: 0.007808
```

Alternatively, converting to time series and using `dynlm`:

```
dft <- as.ts(df)
library(dynlm)
reg4 <- dynlm(ffr ~ cpi + gap + L(ffr,1), dft)
```

Results:

```
> summary(reg4)

Time series regression with "ts" data:
Start = 2, End = 11

Call:
dynlm(formula = ffr ~ cpi + gap + L(ffr, 1), data = dft)

Residuals:
      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
-0.012355 -0.006234 -0.004345  0.003007  0.019277 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)  0.0983353  0.0362563   2.712   0.0350 *
cpi         -0.0009486  0.0058926  -0.161   0.8774  
gap          0.0215892  0.0066774   3.233   0.0178 *
L(ffr, 1)    0.6821619  0.2476126   2.755   0.0331 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.01254 on 6 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.844, Adjusted R-squared:  0.7659 
F-statistic: 10.82 on 3 and 6 DF,  p-value: 0.007808
```

Hope it helps.

---

**EDIT after comments:** some clarifications on why `lag` did not work.

Maybe you will see more clearly how `lag` works in a time series with this toy example in which the series has proper time values:

```
> test <- ts(rnorm(48), start=c(2012), frequency=12)
             Jan         Feb         Mar         Apr         May         Jun         Jul         Aug         Sep         Oct
2012  0.55388567 -1.44187059 -1.81896266 -1.44285425 -1.37991005 -0.49844787 -1.26719606 -0.49876644  1.89507307 -0.74584888
2013  1.55083914  0.15779179  0.58075346  0.90677437  0.31632688 -0.20882555  0.05336465 -0.22241098 -0.11031220  0.12591051
2014  1.49442765  1.87654149 -1.18599539  1.72865701 -0.90245650  0.19460586  0.16168719  0.16245094  1.30435313  1.27952402
2015  0.53370893 -0.74539203 -0.47584512  0.19720682 -1.50906070 -0.21765018  1.03436621 -0.42588233 -0.15680010 -1.46725844
             Nov         Dec
2012  0.64720686 -0.88955517
2013  0.53687326 -0.04852013
2014  0.02273335  0.33675748
2015 -0.24954432 -0.89610509
> lag(test)
             Jan         Feb         Mar         Apr         May         Jun         Jul         Aug         Sep         Oct
2011                                                                                                                        
2012 -1.44187059 -1.81896266 -1.44285425 -1.37991005 -0.49844787 -1.26719606 -0.49876644  1.89507307 -0.74584888  0.64720686
2013  0.15779179  0.58075346  0.90677437  0.31632688 -0.20882555  0.05336465 -0.22241098 -0.11031220  0.12591051  0.53687326
2014  1.87654149 -1.18599539  1.72865701 -0.90245650  0.19460586  0.16168719  0.16245094  1.30435313  1.27952402  0.02273335
2015 -0.74539203 -0.47584512  0.19720682 -1.50906070 -0.21765018  1.03436621 -0.42588233 -0.15680010 -1.46725844 -0.24954432
             Nov         Dec
2011              0.55388567
2012 -0.88955517  1.55083914
2013 -0.04852013  1.49442765
2014  0.33675748  0.53370893
2015 -0.89610509
```

The function is not really changing the column itself, but the time values in which it is associated. However, doing it with the "normal" dataframe in your example:

```
> df$ffr
 [1] 0.12 0.09 0.09 0.07 0.09 0.09 0.10 0.11 0.12 0.13 0.16
> lag(df$ffr)
 [1] 0.12 0.09 0.09 0.07 0.09 0.09 0.10 0.11 0.12 0.13 0.16
attr(,"tsp")
[1]  0 10  1
```

You see that even if it is not a time series, `lag` is adding a `tsp` attribute to it (see `?tsp`), but the values themselves do not change, nor the indexes, and that's why you see a perfect fit when you use it with `lm`.

On the other hand, if you do it with the dataframe converted to time series,

```
> dft[,2]
Time Series:
Start = 1 
End = 11 
Frequency = 1 
 [1] 0.12 0.09 0.09 0.07 0.09 0.09 0.10 0.11 0.12 0.13 0.16
> lag(dft[,2])
Time Series:
Start = 0 
End = 10 
Frequency = 1 
 [1] 0.12 0.09 0.09 0.07 0.09 0.09 0.10 0.11 0.12 0.13 0.16
```

again it is changing the metadata but not the values or the indexes, and `lm` does not understand the difference.

As a side point, you could select your lag when using `shift`, second argument by default to 1, see `?shift`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Using `dynlm` seems to work! and it keeps the convenience of working freely with different lags, putting them directly into the formula with `lag` or `L` -- whereas `shift` is less flexible in this sense. One last thing puzzles me: with `dynlm` the output is different when lagging with lag() or with L(), any idea of the reason?

Comment: Thanks! Oh, last question: `shift` isn't part of any package nor built in R, right?

Comment: You're welcome! I think there are several `shift`'s in different packages, but the one I use is in `data.table`.